# Python game: How to eliminate letters by striking the corresponding keys?

Tags: pygame

1. Introduction: Different letters fall down from the top of the screen after a time interval and the letter will vanish while you strike the corresponding key on the keyboard. The x position of each letter is random and the falling speed will accelerate as the game progress. Game will end under a certain condition(e.g. more than 10 letters fall to the bottom).
2. Progress:I have implemented some functions such as generating random falling letters.
3. Problem: I am in bewilderment as how to eliminate each falling letter by striking the corresponding key?

The following are my codes:

1. alphabet_zoo.py

```
import pygame
import time
from pygame.locals import *
from settings import Settings
import game_functions as gf

def run_game():
    pygame.init()
    az_settings =Settings()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0,0), RESIZABLE)
    pygame.display.set_caption("Alphabet Zoo")
    letters = pygame.sprite.Group()
    start = time.time()
    sleepTime = 3


    while True:
        now = time.time()
        gf.check_events(letters)
        letters.update()
        gf.update_screen(az_settings, screen, letters)
        if now - start >sleepTime:
            gf.letter_generator(az_settings ,screen, letters)
            start = now


run_game()
```

2. settings.py

```
class Settings():
    def __init__(self):
        self.bg_color = (0, 0, 0)
        self.letter_speed_factor = 10
```

3. game_functions.py

```
import sys
import pygame
from letter import Letter

def letter_generator(az_settings, screen, letters):
    new_letter = Letter(az_settings, screen)
    letters.add(new_letter)

def check_events(letters):
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                # Here is my question:
                # How could I eliminate each falling letter by striking the corresponding key?
                letters.empty()

def update_screen(az_settings, screen, letters):
    screen.fill(az_settings.bg_color)
    letters.draw(screen)
    letters.update()
    pygame.display.flip()
```

4. letter.py

```
import pygame
import random
from pygame.sprite import Sprite


class Letter(Sprite):

    def __init__(self, az_settings, screen):
        super().__init__()
        self.screen = screen
        self.az_settings = az_settings
        a = random.randint(97, 123)
        c = chr(a)
        if c == 'a':
            self.image = pygame.image.load('images/A.png')
        elif c == 'b':
            self.image = pygame.image.load('images/B.png')
        elif c == 'c':
            self.image = pygame.image.load('images/C.png')
        elif c == 'd':
            self.image = pygame.image.load('images/D.png')
        elif c == 'e':
            self.image = pygame.image.load('images/E.png')
        elif c == 'f':
            self.image = pygame.image.load('images/F.png')
        elif c == 'g':
            self.image = pygame.image.load('images/G.png')
        elif c == 'h':
            self.image = pygame.image.load('images/H.png')
        elif c == 'i':
            self.image = pygame.image.load('images/I.png')
        elif c == 'j':
            self.image = pygame.image.load('images/J.png')
        elif c == 'k':
            self.image = pygame.image.load('images/K.png')
        elif c == 'l':
            self.image = pygame.image.load('images/L.png')
        elif c == 'm':
            self.image = pygame.image.load('images/M.png')
        elif c == 'n':
            self.image = pygame.image.load('images/N.png')
        elif c == 'o':
            self.image = pygame.image.load('images/O.png')
        elif c == 'p':
            self.image = pygame.image.load('images/P.png')
        elif c == 'q':
            self.image = pygame.image.load('images/Q.png')
        elif c == 'r':
            self.image = pygame.image.load('images/R.png')
        elif c == 's':
            self.image = pygame.image.load('images/S.png')
        elif c == 't':
            self.image = pygame.image.load('images/T.png')
        elif c == 'u':
            self.image = pygame.image.load('images/U.png')
        elif c == 'v':
            self.image = pygame.image.load('images/V.png')
        elif c == 'w':
            self.image = pygame.image.load('images/W.png')
        elif c == 'x':
            self.image = pygame.image.load('images/X.png')
        elif c == 'y':
            self.image = pygame.image.load('images/Y.png')
        else:
            self.image = pygame.image.load('images/Z.png')

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

        self.rect.centerx = random.randint(0, self.screen_rect.right)
        self.rect.top = self.screen_rect.top
        self.center = float(self.rect.centerx)


    def update(self):
        if self.rect.bottom < self.screen_rect.bottom:
            self.rect.centery += self.az_settings.letter_speed_factor
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keydown event returns the ascii value of the key. you can delete the falling key with a couple changes.

- In the letter class, make the ascii value public
- In the game loop, update the letter list each time a ket is pressed

Here is the updated code

**letter.py**

```
class Letter(Sprite):

    def __init__(self, az_settings, screen):
        super().__init__()
        self.screen = screen
        self.az_settings = az_settings
        a = random.randint(97, 123) #lowercase a-z
        c = chr(a)
        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/'+c.upper()+'.png')   # letter image file
        self.ascii = a  # make ascii value public

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

        self.rect.centerx = random.randint(0, self.screen_rect.right)
        self.rect.top = self.screen_rect.top
        self.center = float(self.rect.centerx)


    def update(self):
        if self.rect.bottom < self.screen_rect.bottom:
            self.rect.centery += self.az_settings.letter_speed_factor
```

**game_functions.py**

```
import sys
import pygame
from letter import Letter

def letter_generator(az_settings, screen, letters):
    new_letter = Letter(az_settings, screen)
    letters.add(new_letter)

def check_events(letters):
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            letters = [ltr for ltr in letters if ltr.ascii != event.key]  # remove key ascii from letter list

def update_screen(az_settings, screen, letters):
    screen.fill(az_settings.bg_color)
    letters.draw(screen)
    letters.update()
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: The added code ` letters = [ltr for ltr in letters if ltr.ascii != event.key]` in game_functions.py does not work. I've changed it into `            for ltr in letters:
                if ltr.ascii == event.key:
                    letters.remove(ltr)
`. Now it functions perfectly.

Comment: Another thing I have to point out is that sometimes the pygame.image.load() runs well while sometimes the system hints ' pygame.error: Couldn't open images/{.png'. I don't know how  '{' comes out.

Comment: I have finally found the bug.  `a = random.randint(97, 123)` should be changed to ` a = random.randint(97, 122)`